# apache server 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2

I have installed apache server 2.2 from [this site](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/install-apache-windows-7.php) and am trying to start apache but it shows me the following errors:

```
could not bind  to address  0.0.0:80  could not  reliably determine   server's fully  qualifed domain  name  using  192.168.1.100 for server name
```

Please help. Would it be more helpfull how  copy full screenshot from command line?

Comment: You've probably have a typo in the config. It should be 0.0.0.0:80, not 0.0.0:80.

Answer (score 0):

you computer doesn't have a ptr record associated with the IP address.   Add your computer name/ip to your hosts file (on windows I think it is in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt), or set a servername configuration directive in apache config.  But this should probably be over on serverfault.com as opposed to here.  but the cannot bind could either be typo, or could be that port 80 already in use, IIS installed/running)

Comment: how please help

Comment: well edit the server config file (wherever you installed it). But per your other question, if you see it works, then you have apache installed and running.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer but are you running Skype on your Windows machine? Because skype uses port 80 which in turn will not allow you to run a webserver, however you can change the settings in skype to use a different port then try running Apache again.

Answer (score 0):

From your [duplicate question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459871/apacher-server-running/3460051), it looks like you're already running IIS on that port, so Apache HTTPD can't start instead of it (unless you've configured your Apache HTTPD server to show the IIS welcome image, but that's *very* unlikely to be the default configuration).

Shut down IIS first.